# Scripting passowrd with metacharacters

Tags: unix

I am working on a FTP script with a password set by the vendor. Let's say the password is set for 123456! The script fails at the point of login.

If I login in manually, the password works.

PASSWORKD="123456!" or '123456!' or ''123456'!'' -All return 123456! if I echo $PASSWORD but fail at login. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: so far i understand you have an FTP server? first of all you can try to see if you can login into the FTP server [FTP Online Tester](https://ncomputers.org/ftptest)

Comment: The Id & Password work without issue when manually entered.